# Can you create a Google Doc through an app and allow "Open With" through Google Drive and not just your app?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive Realtime API. I can successfully create the doc and have it show up in a user's Drive list. But when they open it, they only hit the Open URL, which routes them to my application. But can I allow them to open the doc with Google Docs instead of coming back to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a google doc, its your own custom format. Google drive wont know how to preview it thus it opens it with your app.

Comment: I see - that makes sense. Is there a way to signal to Google that it's just a collaborative string and allow it to be opened as a Google Doc all the same?